# Ask the proof of compact linear transformations are necessarily bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis

A linear transformation $T$ from a normed space $X_1$ into another normed space $X_2$ is compact if for any bounded sequence $\{ x_n\} \in X_1, \{Tx_n \}$ contains a convergent subsequence in $X_2$.

Note that compact linear transformations are necessarily bounded. The textbook gives an outline of proof:

Suppose that instead $T$ were unbounded. Then, we could find a bounded sequence $\{ x_n\} \in X_1$ for which $||Tx_n||_2 \geq n$ for each $n$ and, consequently, $\{Tx_n \}$ would not contain a convergent subsequence.

I am trying to give a more rigorous step of that "we could find a bounded sequence $\{ x_n\} \in X_1$ for which $||Tx_n||_2 \geq n$ for each $n$".

An operator $T$ is said to be unbounded if there does not exist a constant $M > 0$ such that $\|Tx\|_2 \leq M\|x\|_1$ for all $x \in X_1$. In formal terms, this means:

$$\nexists M > 0 : \|Tx\|_2 \leq M\|x\|_1, \forall x \in X_1.$$

Given that $T$ is unbounded, for each positive integer $n$, there exists a vector $x_n \in X_1$ such that:

$$\|Tx_n\|_2 > n\|x_n\|_1.$$

To ensure the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is bounded, we normalize it to create a new sequence $\{y_n\}$ defined by:

$$y_n = \frac{x_n}{n\|x_n\|_1}.$$

This sequence is bounded because:

$$\|y_n\|_1 = \frac{1}{n},$$

for all $n$, ensuring that $\{y_n\}$ remains within a bounded range in $X_1$.

For this new sequence $\{y_n\}$, considering the linear transformation $T$, we have:

$$\|T(y_n)\|_2 = \frac{1}{n\|x_n\|_1}\|Tx_n\|_2.$$

Given that $\|Tx_n\|_2 > n\|x_n\|_1$ by construction, it follows that:

$$\|T(y_n)\|_2 > 1,$$

But it doesn't give me the desired proof.

Comment: Did you try to use the definition of a bounded operator? $T$ is bounded if and only if the image of the unit sphere $\{x\in X: ||x||=1\}$ is bounded. So if it is unbounded...

Comment: @Mark I add more details in my attempt proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is worth mentioning that each time you found a vector $x_{n} \in X_{1}$ such that $\|T(x_{n}) \|_{2} > n\|x_{n}\|_{1}$, it follows that $x_{n} \neq 0$, so that is why you can divide by $\|x_{n}\|_{1}$ as it is positive.

You had the right idea, but note that also dividing by a factor of $n$ in your $y_{n}$ terms caused a problem later on when looking at $\|T(y_{n})\|_{2}$. Instead, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, try defining

$$y_{n} := \frac{1}{\|x_{n}\|_{1}}x_{n}.$$

Then you can check that $\|y_{n}\|_{1} = 1$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so that $(y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence. From there, you can show that $\|T(y_{n})\|_{2} > n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This obtains your desired result.

It is worth noting that if you use that a linear operator from one normed space into another normed space is bounded if and only if its image on the closed unit ball is bounded, then the result is almost immediate. Because if $T$ is not bounded, then $\{ \|T(x)\|_{2} : x\in B_{X_{1}}\}$ is not bounded, where $B_{X_{1}} = \{x\in X_{1} : \|x\|_{1} \leq 1\}$. So for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, you can find some $x_{n} \in B_{X_{1}}$ such that $\|T(x_{n}) \|_{2} \geq n$, because otherwise $n$ would be an upper bound for $\{ \|T(x)\|_{2} : x\in B_{X_{1}}\}$ and that cannot occur. And the sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is contained in $B_{X_{1}}$, so it is a bounded sequence.